# Recommendation needed in making selectbox or dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a dropdown like this but unable to find any example yet

is it possible if yes please refer any article

[image]

Comment: Since you saw it somewhere, it's possible. With basic css styles you can replicate it, come back with your best effort and SO will help.

Comment: You should use some JS plugin, for example [jQuery Selectric](https://selectric.js.org/demo.html) to create custom dropdown, and use CSS to style it as you need. Check demos on official jQuery Selectric page.